# Как запустить код "Появление блока, окна, текста с задержкой" по клику?

Tags: javascript, окно

этот код запускается при загрузки страницы, а как его запустить по клику на кнопку?

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var i = 5;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        i--;
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 'Осталось секунд: ' + i;
        if (i == 0) {
            document.getElementById('example').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'none';
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
<div id="example" style=" display: none; ">
Содержимое скрытого блока, например ссылка на стачивание или какой-то код.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function delayedText() {
    var i = 5;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        i--;
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 'Осталось секунд: ' + i;
        if (i == 0) {
            document.getElementById('example').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'none';
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000)
}
// comment if not needed - window.onload = delayedText; 


<button type="button" onclick="delayedText()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот то что мне надо:

```js
function startTimer () {
    var i = 5;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        i--;
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = 'Осталось секунд: ' + i;
        if (i == 0) {
            document.getElementById('example').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('timer').style.display = 'none';
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="startTimer()">Старт</button>

<div id="timer"></div>
<div id="example" style="display: none;">
Содержимое скрытого блока, например ссылка на стачивание или какой-то код.
</div>
```